# Swift 3. xCode8. Assignment of value to attribute of Boolean type of an entity raises error

Tags: swift, core-data, ios10

Core data

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer

        let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
        for item in items {
          let game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! GameEntity
          game.str = item.str
          game.rating = item.rating
          game.isConquered = false
```

when executing assignment to game.conquered I am getting:

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

In data model

```
extension GameEntity {

  @nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest< GameEntity > {
    return NSFetchRequest< GameEntity >(entityName: "Game");
  }

  @NSManaged var conquered: Bool
  @NSManaged var rating: Int32
  @NSManaged var str: String?
}
```

**In model explorer in xCode conquered has type Boolean**
I tried to state type for conquered as Boolean in code, but got compiler error - that it can't be represented as NSManaged.

I know I can use Int32 instead of Bool, and differentiate between 0/1 values, I just want to understand what is the reason of error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

after I renamed isConquered to conquered issue has been solved.
So, as I understand issue was in the prefix is, is there any rules in standard that stipulates that some prefixes shouldn't be used for attribute's names??